# Dúvida Código Python e Opencv2

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Nesse código eu consigo fazer a detecção facial a partir de uma webcan. Eu uso a camera do meu notebook. Eu quero que esse código emita uma mensagem de texto, por exemplo "Pessoa Detectada" toda vez q ele detectar um rosto. Eu tentei colocar um "if" mas me atrapalhei.

```
(if len(facesDetectadas)>=1:
        print ("PESSOA DETECTADA")
```

Outra dúvida que eu tenho é que nesse código eu estou acessando a câmera do meu notebook (`video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`). Se eu quiser acessar uma câmera q esteja conectada a um servidor, como ficaria essa linha de código?

Abaixo segue o meu código. Obrigado pela atenção.

```
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
classificadorFace = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

while True:
    conectado, frame = video.read()

    frameCinza = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    facesDetectadas = classificadorFace.detectMultiScale(frameCinza, minSize=(70,70))
    for (x, y, l, a) in facesDetectadas:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + l, y + a), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    cv2.imshow('Vídeo', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('a'):
        break

    if len(facesDetectadas)>=1:
        print ("PESSOA DETECTADA")

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Olá @Rodrigo, vejo que você já e membro do site a algum tempo, porém me parece que você ainda não esta muito ambientado de como o site funciona então vale apena você dar uma olhada no nosso [Tour], digo isso porque estou vendo que você fez um total de 9 perguntas até o momento e apesar das repostas dadas a você terem ajudado você nunca aceitou uma resposta, apesar de parecer que a mesma resolveu seu problema. Isso não é bom para a saúde do site, porque sua pergunta fica como **não resolvida**, ao aceitar uma resposta recompensara quem te ajudou e ajudara quem tiver p msm problema. =D

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Olhei o tour do site e achei ótimo. Não havia me atentado para esse detalhe e ja corrigi isso. Grato pela atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Eu quero que esse código emita uma mensagem de texto, por exemplo "Pessoa Detectada" toda vez q ele detectar um rosto.

Você está fazendo certo. Ao fazer a verificação `if len(facesDetectadas)>=1`, você está verificando se houve ao menos uma face detectada. Eu testei seu código e tudo funcionou conforme esperado.

Verifique se não está tendo nenhum erro com seu código. Por exemplo, se o arquivo `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` está dentro de uma pasta chamada `cascades` no mesmo diretório do seu arquivo `.py`.

Verifique também se você está acessando a webcam corretamente. Com esse seu código, é esperado que abra uma janela com o streaming da sua webcam e, ao reconhecer um rosto, este deve ficar com um quadrado vermelho em volta dele.

A sua cláusula `if` está correta. Se você ainda estiver com erros, é com outra parte da execução do seu código.

> Se eu quiser acessar uma câmera q esteja conectada a um servidor, como ficaria essa linha de código?

Você vai ter que acessar a câmera pelo endereço de rede e porta dela.

`video = cv2.VideoCapture('endereço_ip:porta')`

Veja o endereço exato do streaming da câmera que você deseja trabalhar. Pode ser que esteja ainda dentro de uma função javascript em diretório no endereço especificado, por exemplo:

`video = cv2.VideoCapture('endereço_ip:porta/?action=stream')`

Ou em um MJPEG:

`video = cv2.VideoCapture('endereço_ip:porta/nome_do_arquivo.mjpeg')`

Há diversas outras formas, mas tudo vai depender da configuração de instalação da sua câmera.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Se ainda estiver com erro depois de verificar o que eu disse, mostra aqui pra gente ajudar.